# How to play the audio / video file without touch events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, audio, video

I have a question on audio / video playing for mobile devices without user interaction (touch events)?

How to play the audio / video file without touch events? On googling I had found that

In ipad device browsers, Safari 4+ above versions are  able to play the audio / video file with user interactions only. But I need to play the audio / video files without user interactions in latest versions.

Is it possible to play the video and audio file with single click operation?

For more details:
Example:

In device  browsers (ios /android) we are loading a html page. Here, Html page loads the  video files,audio files. User can play few user interactive operations on the html page. When user perform operations parallely audio files will played based on the selection of operation. To resolve the issue,let us know any approaches.